# Complex sentence structure with seperable verbs and ‘whether’

Tags: sentence-structure, separable-verb

> Ich rufe jetzt zu fragen, ob das Motorrad fertig ist, an.

What would be a correct formulation for this sentence in order to include all elements, but still not to sound silly?

Comment: Unsure whether I should just edit this in, but as adjan mentioned, *um zu* would be the correct infinitive here. Also, you would likely include a third comma before *(um) zu*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s reduce your sentence to the underlying main clause:

> Ich rufe jetzt, um zu fragen, ob das Motorrad fertig ist, an.
>   Ich rufe jetzt, um (etwas) zu fragen, an. (Commas superfluous)
>   Ich rufe jetzt (wegen etwas) an.

As you see, the last thing removed was an infinitive construction which would use *um zu* (rather than simple *zu*). These are most often placed in the *Nachfeld*, i.e. the bit of the sentence *behind* the second part of the separable verb, especially if they are longer/more complex. Thus the most simple word order would be:

> Ich rufe jetzt an, um zu fragen, ob das Motorrad fertig ist.

Pulling the infinitive and its subordinate clause into the *Verbklammer* — i.e. between *rufe* and *an* is possible but very, very untypical. It will happen more often (but still rarely) if the infinitive construction is replaced by a subordinate clause.

> Ich rufe jetzt, weil ich fragen möchte, ob das Motorrad fertig ist, an.

Sometimes, comedians use this for a hilarious effect, when they build incredibly long sentences and then have a list of particles at the end. I believe there should at least be an example by Karl Valentin, but I’m too lazy to look for it now.

Bottom line: **Keep the main clause together unless absolutely necessary.** Thus, say:

> Ich rufe jetzt **an**, um zu fragen, ob das Motorrad fertig ist.

Answer (score 6):

Sentences which talk about a intention ("*do sth. in order to*") use the "*um zu*" - infinitive pattern:

> Ich rufe jetzt an, **um zu** fragen, ob das Motorrad fertig ist.